# How to query only the users who have signed up for specific application in use Azure B2C GraphAPI?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

If I have single Azure B2C tenant with many applications in it, how can I use the Graph API to query users who have signed up for a specific application?

My assumption was that B2C tenants would behave like normal AAD tentants where the application registrations inside it are not merely different Clients and WebAPIs all related to the same overall app across platforms where a single user database makes sense.

Full scenario:
User A signs up for Application X.
User A signs up for Application Y.
User B signs up for Applicaionn X.
User C signs up for Application Y.

When my Application X reads /users it is expected to return A and B, but not C.
Likewise, when Application Y reads /users it is expected to return A and C, but not B.

I could probably come up with some custom attribute solution, but I assume B2C takes care of this?

If not, I suppose I could have convention of creating separate B2C tenants for each different set of applications, but to me this is cumbersome process of setting attributes, policies etc just to isolate users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Azure AD B2C does not currently have first class support for application assignments.**

You can request this feature in the [Azure AD B2C Feedback Forum](http://aka.ms/aadb2c)

As you've indicated, you'll need to implement this yourself. Some options include:

1. Leveraging Azure AD B2C custom attributes to keep track which applications a user signed up for.
2. Leveraging Azure AD groups, adding users to groups that map to applications and then querying for those group members.
3. Keeping this app to user relationship entirely on your application side.